# Find the value of all $x$ satisfying $(f\circ g\circ g\circ f)(x)=(g\circ g\circ f)(x)$, where $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, roots

> Let $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)\ \forall\ x\in \mathbb R$.
>   Then find the value of all $x$ satisfying $(f\circ g\circ g\circ f)(x)=(g\circ g\circ f)(x)$, where $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$.

**Solution.** From the given data, we have 
$(f\circ g\circ g\circ f)(x)=(\sin(\sin(x^2)))^2$ and $(g\circ g\circ f)(x)=\sin(\sin(x^2))$.

Now we have to find the values of $x$ satisfying 
$$(\sin(\sin(x^2)))^2=\sin(\sin(x^2))\tag{1}$$

Let $\sin(\sin(x^2))=t$, then $(1)$ becomes $t^2=t\implies t=0 \text{ or }1$

Case 1: $\sin(\sin(x^2))=0\implies \sin(x^2)=n\pi, n\in \mathbb Z$. Need help in proceeding further

Case 2: $\sin(\sin(x^2))=1\implies \sin(x^2)=n\pi+(-1)^n \left (\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$. Need help in proceeding further

Comment: Please edit the text in RED"Need help in proceeding further"

Comment: do you mean $f(g(g(f(x))))=g(g(f(x)))$

Comment: @HenryLee:Yeah,you got it  right

Comment: Your solution for Case 2, while accurate, is not optimal. For example, the solution is the same for $n=0$ and $n=1.$ Ideally, we'd like a different solution for each $n,$ such as by $\frac\pi2+2n\pi$ for $n\in\Bbb Z.$

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\sin$ is a bounded function between $-1$ and $1$. So the only way that $\sin(x^2)$ is of the form $n\pi$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is when $n=0$. You can then solve this easily for $x$.

Can you solve case $2$ in a similar manner?

EDIT: As for case $2$, as @CameronBuie remarked in the comment, the usual writing of the solutions of $\sin(z)=0$ is $z=\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$. Note that no real number of this form lie between $1$ and $-1$ (the least such positive real number is $\frac{\pi}{2}=1.57\ldots$ and the greatest negative real number of this form is $\frac{\pi}{2}-2\pi=-4.71\ldots$). Hence, there is **no solution** in the case $2$ where $\sin(x^2)=\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$.

Comment: :Following your comment ,$\sin(x^2)=0\implies$ $x^2=n\pi \implies x=\pm \sqrt {n\pi}$.Am i correct?

Comment: Exactly ! Note that necessarily, $n$ is non-negative.

Comment: :will you please clarify case 2 also?

Comment: @PKStyles I added the case $2$ in my answer.